# Sending data through Popups in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am implementing an application in **WPF**.

In one case, I use a Page to display the contents hosted on an ***Apache Server*** by reading the IP of the server. On the same page I have a ***Configure IP*** button which on clicking gives a `Popup` where the IP can be changed so as to specify a different Apache Server. On making this change the Page displaying the content should immediately reload to display the appropriate server's contents.
How can this be achieved? Any help please.

Comment: Is the code for the `popup` in the same class, or is popup a separate child window? Also how is the ip change saved in the popup window, is a button clicked which will then trigger the reload?

Comment: Yes the code is in the same class and clicking a button like 'OK' on the popup window should trigger the reload

Answer (score 0):

Have a method in your main page called `Reload`, have ip as a parameter.

```
private void Reload(string ip)
{
    //do reload stuff using the ip param
}
```

Then trigger this reload sub when the "OK" button in your popup window is clicked. (Assuming you have a text box where the ip is configurable)

```
private void OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Reload(TxtIP.Text);
}
```